# How to add a Xcode localization language via Fastlane script

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, fastlane

I have a project with multiple app targets and need to be able to add an existing English localized string file to one of the targets for development use only.

**Here is my scenario:**

1. Target A uses English + multiple non-English localized strings files.
2. Target B uses only 1 non-English localized strings file.
3. Target B cannot have English strings included in App Store builds.

However, to help during development we currently manually add the English strings to Target B's localization files *(using the existing file from Target A when prompted)*, and remove it prior to App Store submission.

Since we run Fastlane setup/teardown scripts already, I would like to automate adding/removing the English strings from the scripts so we don't have to do it manually every time.

In the Fastfile, I know how to add a file to Target B, but since the Localization files/references are structured a bit differently in Xcode than regular files I am not sure what the proper way to do it is.

**Here is what I have so far:**

```
def add_english_localization()
    require 'xcodeproj'

    project = Xcodeproj::Project.open("../Code/#{XCODE_PROJ}")

    app_target = project.targets.first #Target B
    english_file_ref = project.main_group.new_file('../Code/TargetA/Application/Supporting Files/en.lproj') #Existing english file in Target A's directory
    app_target.add_file_references([english_file_ref]) #This adds the file but doesn't properly update Xcode's Localization references...?

    project.save
  end
```

**Screenshots:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You might be able to do it using [Xcodeproj](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj), though I don't know how. I know that checking those adds some lines to your `project.pbxproj` file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a little ruby script, using xcodeproj to remove and add localization:

To remove language (french in this example):

```
require 'xcodeproj'
project_path = './Whatever.xcodeproj'
project = Xcodeproj::Project.open(project_path)

for o in project.objects do 
    if o.is_a? Xcodeproj::Project::Object::PBXGroup
        if o.hierarchy_path == "/TargetA/Localizable.strings"
            group = o
            break
        end
    end
end


files = group.files
for file in files do

    if file.path == "fr.lproj/Localizable.strings"
        file.remove_from_project
        puts "Removed " + file.path
    end
end

project.save
```

To add language (also french):

```
require 'xcodeproj'
project_path = './Whatever.xcodeproj'
project = Xcodeproj::Project.open(project_path)

for o in project.objects do 
    if o.is_a? Xcodeproj::Project::Object::PBXGroup
        if o.hierarchy_path == "/TargetA/Localizable.strings"
            group = o
            break
        end
    end
end

file = project.new_file("fr.lproj/Localizable.strings")
file.move(group)
file.name = "fr"

project.save
```

You should be able to call it in fastfile, but I didn't check that... You could call it directly using `sh("ruby ./name.rb")`

Comment: Thanks for the scripts! However, the issue I am having actually isn't just moving the file, but instead adding the proper reference to the xcode project so that the english language is "enabled" (see screenshots). It doesn't seem like my original way of adding a header reference does the special trick to enable a localized language. Any suggestions?

Comment: The script is not moving the file - it's adding/removing the file from .xcodeproj, same as selecting the checkbox. The file in this context is reference from .xcodeproj. You can test the script, just run add/remove file script, and try git diff. Also make sure that the hierarchy_path is correct. Looks like it's something like `TargetA/Application/Supporting Files/{language}.lproj/Localizable.strings`

Comment: Sorry, the hierarchy path is without `{language.lproj}`

Comment: Awesome! Got it to work after a few tweaks! Thanks so much for the help, this was driving me nuts and couldn't find good documentation around this.